# React + Axios Progress bar

Tags: reactjs, progress-bar, axios

I want to make File Download Progress bar with React + Axios.
So I wrote the code that below. But I got a "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined" error.
Is there anyone can find the problem in my code?
I don't know how to fix it..

```
 progress = async () => {

        let file_url = "https://some_file_url.xlsx";

        axios.get(file_url, {
            onDownloadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
                let percentCompleted = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total);
                console.log(progressEvent.lengthComputable);
                console.log(percentCompleted);
            }
        })
    };
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Are you importing axios in that same component? If so, show us how

Comment: @Jayce444 omg I was importing the wrong library. Thanks for catching that. However, after creating axios like this, the file is not be downloaded. 
Did I approach it in the wrong direction?

Comment: Another approach might be to use a module that does the heavy lifting for you?  eg https://github.com/rikmms/progress-bar-4-axios#readme

Comment: @ak85 Thanks for your comment! I think it will help.